# Why does queue have front but priority queue has top in stl?

Tags: c++, stl, queue, priority-queue

Both are container adaptors and both are defined in the header `<queue>` still they both have different interfaces to access the 'first' element. I can understand the lack of a `back` due to the constraints of the data structure but naming `front` differently confuses me.

Comment: Perhaps it's because, in English, you can be at the front of a queue and you can be a top priority but you can't be at the top of the queue or front-most priority.

Comment: Probably simply because those data structures, although similar in name, have different established terminology for the same operation. Compare for example wikipedia: [Queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_(abstract_data_type)) uses 'front' while [Priority queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue) uses 'top'. "Why the *terminology* is different" is a question about etymology, rather than API design.

Comment: @user2079303 not necessarily, names are a fundamental part of api design and consistency in naming i feel is important as well. If they are named differently then they should have a difference in function

Comment: @AnkurS consistency between API naming and commonly used terminology is in my opinion more important than consistency between naming of different types even within the same API.

Comment: But we arent consistent in our commonly used terminology, for example the "top" of a heap is often called its root for example on https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/?p=26851

Comment: @AnkurS Is there a name in the standard library which refers to the "top" of a heap? I know there is `std::pop_heap`, but that doesn't mention "top", which is the element being popped.

Comment: no not really, I havent found any at least

Answer (score 2):

The `priority_queue` container adaptor is a convenience wrapper for the standard library's heap algorithms, using a sequence container as a classic binary heap. The name `top` likely reflects this association; we speak of the "top" of a heap, since we visualize it as a heap-ordered binary tree, with the element of greatest priority at the root (top).

Answer (score 2):

Yes that's the point.

These are two different adapters. They "adapt" an underlying container to have a specific interface. These two classes "define" the interface that can then used by algorithms.

Why that terminology?

- Well a queue has a `front` and `back`.
- There is not requirement for a priority to queue to get the least prioritized element; it just has the most prioritized element. So I suppose you could have just a `front` but probably to differentiate it from queue they choose `top`. It probably has something to do with the implementation (as it is almost definitely a heap underneath the covers which just has a `top`).